# -fcatch-undefined-behavior only catches local array access thats more than 1 element above the size

Tags: c, clang, llvm-clang

I have a question regarding the catch-undefined-behavior flag in clang.
I tried it out in a big project written in C, where at one point, an integer value (i) supplied by the user arrives. I then added the following code:

```
int arr[3]
arr[i] = 1234;
```

But when I run the code with gdb it only stops when the variable i has a value of 4 or greater. So when I pass value 3 to i it still accesses the array outside of it's bounds without stopping.

Is this a known limitation of -fcatch-undefined-behavior?
Or does it only check if the access is outside of the stack frame, and not outside of local arrays?

Best regards
Christian

P.S.: I use clang+llvm 3.0 as compiler/linker. Target is x86. The program runs inside a xubuntu 12.04 virtual machine on a Windows XP box.

Comment: I may be wrong (I don't know a lot of things about `-fcatch-undefined-behavior`), but the option checks perhaps the validity of the pointer. Since C99, the pointer `arr[3]` is valid (*one-past-the-end* pointer).

Comment: `arr[3]` is not a pointer. `arr+3` would be valid, dereferencing it would not. @Kirilenko

Comment: The -faddress-sanitizer option from clang+llvm 3.1 is able to find this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annex J of the ISO C standard lists the following undefined behaviour relevant to your question:

- Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
  integer type produces a result that does not point into, or just beyond, the same array
  object (6.5.6).
- Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
  integer type produces a result that points just beyond the array object and is used as
  the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated (6.5.6).

According to your post, Clang's `-fcatch-undefined-behavior` seems to only catch the first of those two.